# No python intepreter recognised in PyCharm although python is installed

Tags: python, 22.04, pycharm

My problem is there is no intepreter shown in the choices when i try to select an intepretereven though I have one installed. Even after clicking on show all intepreters. Does this have something to do with global variables or something??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So bottom left where it says Python 3.10 there will be a button called add intepreter or no intepreter.

1. click on it
2. click add new intepreter
3. choose add local
4. select the local installation that is in your pc usually its on /usr/bin directory
   [image]